# How should I represent an AST annotated with additional information?

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have a simple data type representing an AST in some language:

```
data Term = Var String
          | Num Integer
          | Expr [Term]
```

(In reality it would obviously have more constructors than this.)

I can use this to write a simple evaluation function which matches against the AST structure:

```
eval :: Term -> Result
eval (Var name)   = lookup name
eval (Num n)      = return n
eval (Expr exprs) = ...
```

Can I annotate the AST with information like line numbers without changing how the pattern matching works?

(If I didn't mind changing the patterns, I could use record syntax or view patterns, of course.)

Comment: What about a container ADT like `data AtLine a = AtLine Int a`?

Comment: @NikitaVolkov: That's exactly what I would do with something like ViewPatterns. I'm just wondering if there's a nice way to avoid changing the pattern matching at all.

Comment: Why would it affect pattern matching if it's a `Term` type you match on?

Comment: @NikitaVolkov: Because I want to preserve the metadata as I use the terms. E.g. `eval` might raise an error, so I have to know what line of code it came from.

Comment: You can intercept this error in an outer function like `evalAtLine :: AtLine Term -> Result` and rethrow it with the line information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not represent the AST polymorphically

```
data Term term = Var String
      | Num Integer
      | Expr [term]
```

then your orignal `Term` type is

```
newtype SimplTerm = SimplTerm (Term (SimplTerm))
```

and you can easily do what you want with view patterns

```
data AtLine = AtLine (Term AtLine) Integer

view :: AtLine -> Term AtLine
view (AtLine x _) = x

eval (view -> Var name) = lookup name
eval (view -> Num n) = numResult n
eval (view -> Expr expr) = listResult (map eval expr)
```

or making view polymorphic

```
class AST t where
   term :: t -> Term t
instance AST SimplTemr where
   term (SimplTemr x) = x
instance AST AtLine where
   term (AtLine x _) = x

eval :: AST t => t -> Result
eval (view -> Var name) = lookup name
eval (view -> Num n) = numResult n
eval (view -> Expr expr) = listResult (map eval expr)
```

for error handling I wish there was a way to get view patterns to appear in a monad, but that is life (which you could do if the `view` function were done in cps and so took the continuation as an argument rather than returning a value).

Comment: `recursion-schemes` (on hackage) has a `Fix` type and `Foldable` type class that are very similar to `SimpleTemr` and `AST`, respectively.