# Add additional info to haskell type

Tags: haskell

I have Token data type in my program. It looks something like that:

```
data Token
    = StringToken Strin
    | NumberToken Integer
    | IfToken
    | ElseToken
    ... -- lots of tokens here
```

I use this data type in my parser ant it works fine. But now I want to append some additional info to tokens (source location information). So I can change my data type declaration and use records:

```
data Token
    = StringToken {value :: String, srcLoc :: SourceLocation}
    | NumberToken {value :: String, srcLoc :: SourceLocation}
    | IfToken {srcLoc :: SourceLocation}
    | ElseToken {srcLoc :: SourceLocation}
    ... -- lots of tokens here
```

But this solution doesn't seem very practical and beautiful to me. So is there better solution for this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204177/how-should-i-represent-an-ast-annotated-with-additional-information

Comment: @Arjan thanks, it is useful link for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes:

```
data TokenLoc = TokenLoc {tok::Token , srcLoc::SourceLocation}
```

This stores the token and the location together, but cleanly keeps them separate, avoiding the repetition.